# Flutter: Debug Console: What is the meaning of the letters: I, W?

Tags: flutter, debugging, dart

On the debug console sometimes messages appear like `W/IInputConnectionWrapper ...`, `I/zygote ....` or `I/choreographer ....`. What is the meaning of the letters "W" und "I"?

Comment: a `w`arning? `i`nfo? most likely you could see `e`rror too... ;-(

Comment: @pskink : Thank you for your answer. But you have phrased your answer as a question, so I am not sure if you are guessing or if you really know it. If you are sure, please phrase it as a statement.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#Overview

Comment: @pskink : Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by @pskink the `I` stands for `Info` and the `W` stands for `Warning`.

You can encounter the following values:

```
V: Verbose (lowest priority)
D: Debug
I: Info
W: Warning
E: Error
A: Assert
```

More information can be found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat